# How to represent a many-to-many "X contains Y" relationship between a table and itself?

Tags: database-design

I have a table full of foods, such as "Cornish pastry" and "vegetable stew" and "carrots". I want to model the fact that foods can contain other foods. (For instance, a Cornish pastry contains vegetable stew, and vegetable stew contains carrots, but it's plausible that people may eat vegetable stew on its own, or that they might include carrots in a different recipe.)

So I think I should model this by having a many-to-many relation between the food table and itself? That would mean I'd have a separate "food inclusion" table, which would store the containing food's ID, the contained food's ID, and a measure of how much is contained.

The most common problem I'd have to solve here would be "Given this list of foods I've eaten, what quantity of carrots have been consumed?" So I'd have to add together the contribution from eating carrots raw, plus the carrots contained in the vegetable stew that's been eaten, plus the carrots in the vegetable stew in the Cornish pastry that's been eaten, and so on.

Is there some more natural/standard way to represent these sorts of hierarchies?

Comment: This is commonly referred to as Bill Of Materials (BOM). You should be able to find plenty of examples if you search on this term.